# What is Filter interface in Rest Assured Api.. it is used to pass the params in the request?

Tags: bdd, rest-assured, web-api-testing

Can someone provide me example for Filter Interface in REST-assured and found this one only.[link](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.1/io/restassured/filter/Filter.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the api docs:

> A filter allows you to inspect and alter a request before it's
> actually committed and also inspect and alter the response before it's
> returned to the expectations. You can regard it as an "around advice"
> in AOP terms. Filters can be used to implement custom authentication
> schemes, session management, logging etc.

Actually, it is used to extract/log the data from request/response.

Some built-in filters:

- RequestLoggingFilter
- ResponseLoggingFilter
- CookieFilter
- ...

[image]

You can register filters as static settings, for example:

```
RestAssured.filters(new RequestLoggingFilter(), new ResponseLoggingFilter());
```

Then every request you will get the log in console like this.

Request:

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:8000/req2
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 13:59:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 110

{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "nesciunt quas odio",
    "body": "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed"
}
```

A custom sample for Filter can be mentioned is [allure-rest-assured](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-rest-assured/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/restassured/AllureRestAssured.java), or simple one like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323940/7574461

Comment: can we use the Filter to pass params for the request? I could see in my real project something like this..

public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) { requestSpec.queryParams("","")
return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
}

Comment: @jeyasuriyan Technically, yes, you can see the docs https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/specification/FilterableRequestSpecification.html But I don't see any reasons to do this. You can pass `params`  directly from `RequestSpecification`

Comment: @jeyasuriyan hey man, if my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as a correct and upvote it. Thanks.